# How to disable Photos.app launching every time a device is connected

Tags: macos, photos

Every time you connect a device Photos.app opens and you have to disable it for every device one by one.

How do you disable this for all devices you connect?

Comment: @Allan I haven't found it before using the Google and search on this site. You are the first who point me on this question. May be because most of these questions are targeted to previous versions of OS X, not for el-capitan as people looking for. And most guides suggest to disable it for specific devices.

Comment: My suggestion is to not be so specific in your searching.  Instead of specifying "El Capitan" use "OS X" or leave it out altogether.  While El Cap is different, it's not so different that the functionality is drastically changed from one version to the next.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following command to

`defaults -currentHost write com.apple.ImageCapture disableHotPlug -bool YES`

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/photography/comments/3xkrw5/tip_how_to_stop_osx_apple_photos_from_launching/)

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you would sign into your account on a desktop and remove devices that you don't want to download your photos on. That should work. It has for me

Comment: The post is about disabling this feature for any devices you will connect by default.